# Enqueue on filename and not on a template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have sidebar.php and sidebar-closing.php.

Let say I have dashboard.php:

```
<?php
/**
* Template name: Virtuallio Dashboard
*/
?>

<?php include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/virtuallio-template-sidebar.php'); ?>

/*Content goes here*/

<?php include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/virtuallio-template-sidebar-closing.php'); ?>
```

I want to keep it dynamic so I don't want to add "if(is_page('new-page.php')" to functions.php everytime I'm creating a new page.

What I want to happen is to enqueue a script and styling  on sidebar.php since it's call all over the pages (App). I don't need certain styling outside the App.

So it's something like this: `if ($filename == "sidebar.php") { /* enqueue here */}`

Any workaround for this?

Comment: your question is not clear what do you want to do ?

Comment: you need to create a custom `hook` like `wp_head` and enqueue  the script like `add_action("wp_head")` hook?

Comment: i can enqueue using is_page_template() function. But the case here is I'm not using the virtuallio-template-sidebar.php as a template. The template being used is dashboard.php. I want to enqueueue on the actual virtuallio-template-sidebar.php and not on the template dashboard.php (which is the actual page).

Answer (score 0):

Use get_sidebar() function instead of include, then you can

```
function my_enqueued_styles($name) {
 // Check $name here if you want
 wp_enqueue_style($handler, $path);
}
add_action('get_sidebar', 'my_enqueued_styles');
```

Another solution is

```
function custom_sidebar() {
 require_once('...');
 do_action('custom_action');
}

function my_enqueued_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style($handler, $path);
}
add_action('custom_action', 'my_enqueued_styles');
```

And call sidebar as custom_sidebar();

Comment: The sidebar I'm using is a custom php  template. That's not the sidebar of the WordPress.

Comment: No matter. Create sidebar then called sidebar-custom_name.php and use get_sidebar('custom_name')

Comment: Anyways have added alternative solution to the answer